# Google API for Google Docs, requesting a list of documents -- 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android, google-docs, httpresponse, google-api-java-client

After authentication from google servers for google docs, I do a simple getResponse, but I get a 400 Bad Request. I can't understand where am I going wrong. The sample code is, below

```
  private void executeRefreshAlbums() {
        HttpRequest request = transport.buildGetRequest();
        request.url = GoogleDocsUrl.forDefaultPrivateFull();
        System.out.println("URL = "+request.url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = request.execute();
            System.out.println("Response = "+response.getContent());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  }
```

The sysout prints the correct url as

```
03-12 17:36:59.573: INFO/System.out(451): URL = https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full
```

But When I do this, I get

```
03-12 17:43:41.360: WARN/System.err(3958): com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:209)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.example.Test.executeRefreshAlbums(Test.java:198)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.example.Test.authenticated(Test.java:190)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.example.Test.authenticatedClientLogin(Test.java:156)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.example.Test.access$1(Test.java:153)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.example.Test$2$1.run(Test.java:139)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 17:43:41.415: WARN/System.err(3958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-12 17:43:41.422: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-12 17:43:41.422: WARN/System.err(3958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-12 17:43:41.422: WARN/System.err(3958):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I have been trying it for an hour now :-(

Comment: same problem did u get any solution plz help?

Comment: @All for full explanation refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/7230435/689853

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the other thread user @Merlin [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230435/using-goople-api-fetch-documents-list-and-download-them/7337416#7337416) the solution which solved similar issue. His solution was to specify the API version number 3.0 in the request as stated in the "[Google Documents List Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Versioning)" document:

> **Important**: If you make a request to the API that uses a feature only
>   available in version 3, but forget to set the version, you will most
>   likely receive a **400 Bad Request response**. Since the URL structure is
>   different between versions 2 and 3, this is a common mistake made by
>   new users of the API.
>
> To specify a version number, use the
>   `GData-Version` HTTP header. The value of this header must be **`3.0`**. The
>   decimal and the zero are required.
>
> **`GData-Version: 3.0`**
>
> Alternatively,
>   you can specify **`v=3`** as a query parameter in the URL. This is often
>   needed when working behind a firewall that strips HTTP headers, or
>   from some JavaScript requests. Use of the HTTP header is recommended
>   when possible.
>
> https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the `transport` object your using is;

Here is a simple HttpGet request:

```
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(URI);  
        HttpParams params   = new BasicHttpParams();                        
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpResponse response        = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String returnString = "";
        String line = "";
        do
        {
         returnString += line;
         line = in.readLine();
        } while (line != null);
```

Perhaps using this method instead you will get a more obvious error?