# Using Google Api fetch Documents list and download them?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client

Hi i am using the picasa example for android and modifying it but i am not getting any list of documents Plz help i am posting my modified class rest are same as in picasa example?Plz help

m getting `400 bad request in executeRefreshAlbums()` method

FetchGooleDocsActivity(This is the main Activity)

```
package com.fetchgoogledocs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.xml.atom.AtomParser;

public class FetchGooleDocsActivity extends ListActivity {

     private static final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "writely";

      private static final String TAG = "PrinterAppGDOCS";


      private static final int REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE = 0;

      private static final String PREF = "MyPrefs";

      private static final int DIALOG_ACCOUNTS = 0;

      private static HttpTransport transport;

      private String authToken;
      private static Context context;

      private String postLink;
      private final List<AlbumEntry> albums = new ArrayList<AlbumEntry>();
      //private final List<AlbumEntry> albums = new ArrayList<AlbumEntry>();

      public FetchGooleDocsActivity() {
        transport = GoogleTransport.create();
        GoogleHeaders headers = (GoogleHeaders) transport.defaultHeaders;
        headers.setApplicationName("PrinterApp/1.0");
        headers.gdataVersion = "2";
        AtomParser parser = new AtomParser();
        parser.namespaceDictionary = Util.NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY;
        transport.addParser(parser);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context=this;
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        setLogging(settings.getBoolean("logging", false));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          sendData = new SendData(intent, getContentResolver());
          Toast.makeText(context, "Send data initilize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {            
          sendData = null;
        }
        gotAccount(false);
      }

      @Override
      protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
          case DIALOG_ACCOUNTS:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select a Google account");
            final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
            final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
            final int size = accounts.length;
            String[] names = new String[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              names[i] = accounts[i].name;
            }
            builder.setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                gotAccount(manager, accounts[which]);
              }
            });
            return builder.create();
        }
        return null;
      }

      private void gotAccount(boolean tokenExpired) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        String accountName = settings.getString("accountName", null);
        if (accountName != null) {
          AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
          Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
          int size = accounts.length;
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Account account = accounts[i];
            if (accountName.equals(account.name)) {
              if (tokenExpired) {
                manager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", this.authToken);
              }
              gotAccount(manager, account);
              return;
            }
          }
        }
        showDialog(DIALOG_ACCOUNTS);
      }

      private void gotAccount(final AccountManager manager, final Account account) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("accountName", account.name);
        editor.commit();
        new Thread() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              final Bundle bundle =
                  manager.getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, null, null)
                      .getResult();
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                  try {
                    if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {
                      Intent intent =
                          bundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                      int flags = intent.getFlags();
                      flags &= ~Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
                      intent.setFlags(flags);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE);
                    } else if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN)) {
                      authenticatedClientLogin(
                          bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
                    }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    handleException(e);
                  }
                }
              });
            } catch (Exception e) {
              handleException(e);
            }
          }
        }.start();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(
          int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
          case REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              gotAccount(false);
            } else {
              showDialog(DIALOG_ACCOUNTS);
            }
            break;
        }
      }

      private void authenticatedClientLogin(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
        ((GoogleHeaders) transport.defaultHeaders).setGoogleLogin(authToken);
        authenticated();
      }

      static class SendData {         

        String fileName;
        Uri uri;
        String contentType;
        long contentLength;

        SendData(Intent intent, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "Send data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
          if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            Uri uri = this.uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            Toast.makeText(context, scheme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (scheme.equals("content")) {
              Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
              cursor.moveToFirst();
              this.fileName = cursor.getString(
                  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
              this.contentType = intent.getType();
              this.contentLength =
                  cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Images.Media.SIZE));
            }
          }      
        }
      }

      static SendData sendData;

      private void authenticated() {
        if (sendData != null) {
          try {
            if (sendData.fileName != null) {
              boolean success = false;
              try {
                HttpRequest request = transport.buildPostRequest();
                request.url = GdocUrl.relativeToRoot(
                    "default/private/full");
                Toast.makeText(context, request.url.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ((GoogleHeaders) request.headers).setSlugFromFileName(
                    sendData.fileName);
                InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent();
                content.inputStream =
                    getContentResolver().openInputStream(sendData.uri);
                content.type = sendData.contentType;
                content.length = sendData.contentLength;
                request.content = content;
                request.execute().ignore();
                success = true;
              } catch (IOException e) {
                handleException(e);
              }
              setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                  new String[] {success ? "OK" : "ERROR"}));
            }
          } finally {
            sendData = null;
          }
        } else {        
         executeRefreshAlbums();
        }
      }

      private void executeRefreshAlbums() {      
            String[] albumNames;
            List<AlbumEntry> albums = this.albums;
            albums.clear();
            try {
              GdocUrl url = GdocUrl.relativeToRoot("default/private/full");           
              // page through results
              while (true) {
                UserFeed userFeed = UserFeed.executeGet(transport, url);                
                this.postLink = userFeed.getPostLink();
                if (userFeed.albums != null) {
                  albums.addAll(userFeed.albums);
                }
                String nextLink = userFeed.getNextLink();
                if (nextLink == null) {
                  break;
                }
              }
              int numAlbums = albums.size();
              albumNames = new String[numAlbums];
              for (int i = 0; i < numAlbums; i++) {
                albumNames[i] = albums.get(i).title;
              }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              handleException(e);
              albumNames = new String[] {e.getMessage()};
              albums.clear();
            }
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, albumNames));
            Toast.makeText(context, albumNames.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

      private void setLogging(boolean logging) {
        Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client").setLevel(
            logging ? Level.CONFIG : Level.OFF);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        boolean currentSetting = settings.getBoolean("logging", false);
        if (currentSetting != logging) {
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
          editor.putBoolean("logging", logging);
          editor.commit();
        }
      }

      private void handleException(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        boolean log = settings.getBoolean("logging", false);
        if (e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
          HttpResponse response = ((HttpResponseException) e).response;
          int statusCode = response.statusCode;
          try {
            response.ignore();
          } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          if (statusCode == 401 || statusCode == 403) {
            gotAccount(true);
            return;
          }
          if (log) {
            try {
              Log.e(TAG, response.parseAsString());
            } catch (IOException parseException) {
              parseException.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
        if (log) {
          Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
      }
    }
```

GdocUrl

```
package com.fetchgoogledocs;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUrl;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

/**
 * @author Yaniv Inbar
 */
public class GdocUrl extends GoogleUrl {

  public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";

  @Key
  public String kinds;

  public GdocUrl(String encodedUrl) {
    super(encodedUrl);
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a new URL based on the given relative path.
   * 
   * @param relativePath encoded path relative to the {@link #ROOT_URL}
   * @return new URL
   */
  public static GdocUrl relativeToRoot(String relativePath) {
    return new GdocUrl(ROOT_URL + relativePath);
  }
}
```

Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.google.api.client.sample.picasa"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".PicasaDemoActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"></data>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>    
    </application>
</manifest>
```

UserFeed

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class UserFeed extends Feed {

  @Key("entry")
  public List<AlbumEntry> albums;

  public static UserFeed executeGet(HttpTransport transport, GdocUrl url)
      throws IOException {
    url.kinds = "album";
    return (UserFeed) Feed.executeGet(transport, url, UserFeed.class);
  }
}
```

Feed

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.xml.atom.GData;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Yaniv Inbar
 */
public class Feed {

  @Key("link")
  public List<Link> links;

  public String getPostLink() {
    return Link.find(links, "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post");
  }

  public String getNextLink() {
    return Link.find(links, "next");
  }

  static Feed executeGet(HttpTransport transport, GdocUrl url,
      Class<? extends Feed> feedClass) throws IOException {
    url.fields = GData.getFieldsFor(feedClass);
    HttpRequest request = transport.buildGetRequest();
    request.url = url;
    return request.execute().parseAs(feedClass);
  }
}
```

I think my problem lies in `Feed` or `Userfeed` class cause i dont know what to put next in URL

Comment: @Peter Knego m getting 400 bad request in executeRefreshAlbums() method

Comment: What is the URL for the Android Picasa example that you are referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the version.  From the API documentation section called [Specifying a Version](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Versioning) ...

> If you make a request to the API that uses a feature only available in
>   version 3, but forget to set the version, you will most likely receive
>   a 400 Bad Request response. Since the URL structure is different
>   between versions 2 and 3, this is a common mistake made by new users
>   of the API.
>
> To specify a version number, use the GData-Version HTTP header. The
>   value of this header must be 3.0. The decimal and the zero are
>   required.

```
GData-Version: 3.0
```

> Alternatively, you can specify v=3 as a query parameter in the URL.
>   This is often needed when working behind a firewall that strips HTTP
>   headers, or from some JavaScript requests. Use of the HTTP header is
>   recommended when possible.

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3
```