# Java Google Drive API download file

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to download file with Drive Api and get some trouble. I read this guide[downloading file with Drive Api v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia) and use this code

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Every time I am getting this error `

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Errors and suggested actions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#errors_and_suggested_actions):

> Error encountered can mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.
>
> This error can be thrown when trying to add a duplicate parent to a Drive item. It can also be thrown when trying to add a parent that would create a cycle in the directory graph.

You may also try solution advised in [Google API for Google Docs, requesting a list of documents — 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286400/google-api-for-google-docs-requesting-a-list-of-documents-400-bad-request) wherein specifying correct version number in your HTTP GET request could be possible solution for the encountered error.